# How do you write a "Statements addressing the Key Selection Criteria"?

Tags: business-writing

So looking at [This Job](https://www.bendigo.vic.gov.au/About_the_City/The_Organisation/Employment/Current_vacancies/Web_Development_Officer#.VXYkOc-qpBc) and under "Your Checklist" it has 3 different uploads, *Cover Letter*, *Resume* and *Statements addressing the Key Selection Criteria*

now to my understanding the *Statements addressing the Key Selection Criteria* is the *Cover Letter* and a well written Cover Letter explains how you fit with what the employer is looking for.

So what is the difference? and how do i write *Statements addressing the Key Selection Criteria* in general (using the link above as an example)

NOTE: i am not applying for the job linked above as it is too far away however i figured i should get this cleared up in case if i veer come across it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cover letter is a brief, less than one A4 page, summary of why you should get the job. The statements addressing criteria need to cover, in detail, exactly what they set out. The CV sets out, in list form, relevant information.